# Click and drag element with overflow: hidden doesn't trigger onmouseout in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, draggable

It works fine in chrome but not in firefox, in firefox it triggers once you release outside the box, and then move your cursor. Any ideas what causes this behaviour and are there any ways around it?

```js
var testDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");
testDiv.onmouseout = function () {
    alert("Triggered.");
};
```

```css
#testDiv {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
 <div id="testDiv"></div>
```

So click and hold inside the green square, then move your cursor outside.

Mirror on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ntLgyow/

Comment: It triggered once I moved the mouse after releasing outside the box. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Yeah exactly, but why doesn't it behave the same as chrome where it triggers right when you go outside the box?

Comment: What is your version of Firefox?

Comment: 32.0.2, I think it's the latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the last line. firefox has default function for drag so prevent default on mouse down will do.

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");
testDiv.onmouseout = function () {
    alert("Triggered.");
};

testDiv.onmousedown=function(e){e.preventDefault();}
```